# Problems with input & label in defferent div's

Tags: css, input, label, checked

Why rule in CSS does not work?

*index.html* - Two radio buttons. Can't correct HTML code, only CSS!

```
<table class="simplecheckout-methods-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="code">
                    <input type="radio" value="pickup.pickup"id="pickup.pickup" checked="checked">
                </td>
                <td class="title" valign="middle">
                    <label for="pickup.pickup">pickup</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="code">
                    <input type="radio" value="flat1.flat1" id="flat1.flat1">
                </td>
                <td class="title" valign="middle">
                    <label for="flat1.flat1">flat1</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

*style.css* - How can I find this label. If label and input in one tr the code work fine. But as I write before I can't correct index.html

```
.simplecheckout-methods-table input:checked + label {
    background: #B099C0;
}
```

Comment: even if they in the same `tr` this css won't work they must be in the same `td`, because `+` sign will affect only the direct sibling after `input:checked`

Comment: code added properly